# Interpretation of the word tyaktajīvitāḥ in Sanskrit

Tags: bhagavad-gita, translation-request, sanskrit

I am currently listening to some discourses on the Bhagavad Gita. Today I was learning the meaning of BG 1.9:

अन्ये च बहव: शूरा **मदर्थे त्यक्तजीविता:** |

नानाशस्त्रप्रहरणा: सर्वे युद्धविशारदा: || 9||

I have highlighted the phrase I am interested in. mad-artha tyakta-jIvitAh. Here, we have the speaker, talking about a war that hasn't even begun and yet says: "for my sake, they have laid down their lives". Note the past tense there (laid). I would like some clarification on whether tyakta-jIvitAh means "prepared to lay down their lives" or "laid down their lives"?

Please note that while a *literal* translation will be hugely helpful, I am trying to understand the sentence structure too -- namely, why the speaker is using past tense for people that are *alive* at that moment and like I mentioned above, especially given that the war hasn't even begun.

Comment: It is difficult to render sanskrit into english. First, there are no 'sentences' in sanskrit - there are stops, so to understand the sentence structure is a quest that cannot be fulfilled.  Depending upon where the stop is can change the meaning of the verse. It is best to work with several translations to get a better understanding of an entire verse.

Answer (score 1):

Bg. 1.9.:

> अन्ये च बहवः श‍ूरा मदर्थे त्यक्तजीविताः ।
> नानाशस्त्रप्रहरणाः सर्वे युद्धविशारदाः ॥ ९ ॥

> anye ca bahavaḥ śūrā
> mad-arthe tyakta-jīvitāḥ
> nānā-śastra-praharaṇāḥ
> sarve yuddha-viśāradāḥ

Synonyms.:

anye — others; ca — also; bahavaḥ — in great numbers; śūrāḥ — heroes; mat-arthe — for my sake; **tyakta-jīvitāḥ — prepared to risk life;** nānā — many; śastra — weapons; praharaṇāḥ — equipped with; sarve — all of them; yuddha-viśāradāḥ — experienced in military science.

Translation.:

> There are many other heroes **who are prepared to lay down their lives for my sake.** All of them are well equipped with different kinds of weapons, and all are experienced in military science.

Check [this](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/1/9/) site.

I hope this clarifies your queries.